# Unreliable QueryPerformanceCounter on a KVM Windows 2008 RC2 guest

Tags: linux, windows, kvm

I am having some trouble when running a KVM Windows 2008 RC2 x64 guest on an ubuntu 12.04 x64 host. Specifically the Win32 call QueryPerformanceCounter seems to periodically produce unreliable results when compared to clock time. I am running a loop similar to this:

```
auto zero = tbb::tick_count::now ();
while (true) {
  std::cout << datetime::now () 
            << " delta: " << (tbb::tick_count::now () - zero).seconds () 
            << std::endl;
  zero = tbb::tick_count::now ();
  Sleep (1000);
}
```

Above, tbb::tick_count is a thin wrapper over QueryPerformanceCounter and datetime::now() uses the system clock. Periodically, say at least once every 3 minutes, the delta is about 42 seconds. The system clock is always pretty accurate.

Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Comment: How do you determine the ticks per second?

Comment: QueryPerformanceFrequency. Above I use the intel tbb library which handles that for me but I have tried it with straight win32 as well.

Comment: There are various bugs when using QueryPerformanceCounter(), see this [Python PEP about different time functions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0418/#windows-queryperformancecounter). Don't expect it to be 100% reliable under all conditions.

Comment: Spidering from the link that @scai gave, it seems that Sun's VirtualBox had an identical bug - https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/8707 - that had to do with sampling the two halves of the answer without rollover, but was on a windows host. Perhaps linux's KVM has the same bug?

Answer (score 0):

From [Game Timing and Multicore Processors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee417693%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> [...] While QueryPerformanceCounter and QueryPerformanceFrequency
>   typically adjust for multiple processors, bugs in the BIOS or drivers
>   may result in these routines returning different values as the thread
>   moves from one processor to another. So, it's best to keep the thread
>   on a single processor. [...]

The system clock uses a different mechanism to return time. It's generally more reliable at the cost of resolution.